# Normal design for this data

Tags: normalization

How can one best represent this type of data in a relational database?

1. There a variable number of a particular Machine each uniquely serialized by the manufacturer.
2. Each Machine will be set up by the user to do variable number of the tasks that this type of machine is capable of.
3. All the machines will select from the same task list which itself may be altered
   over time
4. Finally each task will have a time setting which will vary from one machine to another.

The final condition seems to mess up my attempts to normalize this.

Comment: Is there only one machine type or are there several? If there are several, do different machine types share some tasks?

Comment: only one machine type but some have higher spec, but some high spec will be set up sometimes to do a subset of the possible tasks

Comment: So several machines all of the same type. One set of tasks but every machine is only capable of performing a subset of all tasks. For each machine a subset of the tasks the machine can theoretically perform is actually scheduled. Correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Machines** :: Id, SerialNumber

Id is the primary key.

**Tasks** :: Id, Description

Id is the primary key.

**MachineTasks** :: MachineId, TaskId

MachineId and TaskId are the composite primary key. MachineId is a foreign key referencing Machines.Id. TaskId is a foreign key  referencing Tasks.Id.

**ScheduledMachineTasks** :: MachineId, TaskId, Time

MachineId and TaskId are the composite primary key. MachineId and TaskId are a composite foreign key referencing MachineTasks.MachineId and MachineTasks.TaskId.

Note that this will only allow to schedule each task only once per machine and requires further extension if one task may be scheduled multiple times per machine.

Comment: Both Durilai and yourself gave very similar answers but I will select yours as the accepted answer as you gave a lot of explanatory information, thanks for your time and knowledge

Answer (score 1):

Create a common table relating each object to each other, with that supplemental data.

**MACHINE TABLE**
ID, MachineID

**TASK TABLE**
ID, Task

**MACHINETASK TABLE**
ID, MachineID (FK to MACHINE.ID), TaskID (FK to TASK.ID), Time

Comment: Thanks, this looks interesting

Comment: The only question I would have is the time field. Is it entered by users, a reference table etc?

Comment: it is entered by the users, depending upon the quality of product they wish to get

Comment: Your design and the accepted one are almost the same but I accepted the other just because of the explanations supplied. Thank you again

Comment: No worries, like to help. Points come regardless.